# Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop 'component' supplied to 'Route' - react-router-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I want to solve this warning. I get this warning once I added react-router-dom to App.js.
(The application itself is working fine with this warning.)

Warning message:

```
index.js:1 Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop 'component' supplied to 'Route': the prop is not a valid React component
    in Route (at App.js:34)
    in App (at src/index.js:9)
    in Router (created by HashRouter)
    in HashRouter (at src/index.js:8)
```

I'm just passing down the state down to the child component form App.js
App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import './App.css'
import MasterPassword from './MasterPassword'
import EncryptForm from './EncryptForm'
import NotFound from './NotFound'

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      masterPassword: null
    }
  }

  getMasterPassword = userPassword => {
    this.setState({
      masterPassword: userPassword
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        {!this.state.masterPassword
        ? <MasterPassword
            path='/ask-password'
            masterPassword={this.state.masterPassword}
            onStorePassword={this.getMasterPassword}
          />
        : <div className="App">
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path='/' render={() => <EncryptForm masterPassword={this.state.masterPassword} />} />
              <Route component={<NotFound />} />
            </Switch>
          </div>}
      </Router>
    )
  } 
}

export default App
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { HashRouter } from 'react-router-dom' 
import './index.css'
import App from './components/App'
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker'

ReactDOM.render(<HashRouter>
        <App />
    </HashRouter>, document.getElementById('root'))

serviceWorker.unregister()
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this `<Route component={<NotFound />} />` to this: `<Route component={NotFound} />`

This is pretty standard behavior for libraries like this. They want to render the component like this: `<component />` rather than like this: `{component}`.

Answer (score 1):

@Asher's answer should work, but if you have props that you'd like to pass in, then you can pass the component in an inline function that creates the React element:

```
<Switch><Route component={() => <NotFound message={notFoundMessage} />}/></Switch>
```

Resource: https://ui.dev/react-router-v4-pass-props-to-components/